# Qt 5 encoding problems

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, utf-8, qt5

I had an application built using Qt 4. It used latin-1 as source and I always used QString::fromLatin1. However, when trying to port to Qt 5 (Actually, I both used Qt 5 and Windows 8 together, but I don't think it's windows' fault) the encoding actually appears kinda right, with some weird space before/after the text.

This is the app running with Qt 5 / Windows 8:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the `ç` and and `ã` do appear correct, with some weird space added between them. Also, the `ó` character appears correct with no space.

This is how I set the QLabel:

```
m_msgWelcome->setText(QString("Bem vindo ao biocódigo!\nSelecione uma opção ao lado para iniciar"));
```

I already tried both `QString::fromUtf8` and `QString::fromLatin1` with no success.

Comment: That's weird, in a real encoding issue I'd expect wrong characters as well. Which encoding does your source file have? Could you reduce the string to "opção" and add the output of m_msgWelcome->text().toUtf8().toHex()? Might be also a font rendering issue with that specific font.

Comment: I get "6f70c3a7c3a36f" toUtf8().toHex(). Changing the font corrected the issue, now i have no idea why this happened since i'm using the same font that was working before. Wanna post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Qt5, normally, you can just saving all your files in UTF-8 (no need to use method like `QString::fromAnythingEncoding`).

With Qt Creator you can do this by : **Edit** then **Select Encoding** (for all your files).

For the future, you can also change the default setting : **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **Behavior** > **Default encoding** then put **UTF-8**.

If the spacing problem is still there try using a different font.

Comment: It was really a rendering issue with the font, though i'm still clueless why. But a big thanks for the encoding tip, i had a *real hard time* converting the files to UTF-8 without losing my accented code.

Comment: My source files are UTF8 but Qt Creator editor does not show accented chars. Do you have idea? It is a problem in editor, nothing to do with compilation.